# What's the pair of numbers made using 1-9 which has maximum product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The task is to find a pair of numbers whose digits are 1-9, no digit repeated such that their product is maximum possible.

eg. 123 and 456789 is one such pair.

**Question:** Please suggest a way to do it.

I tried writing a code in Python but failed. Any logical approach is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a Project Euler problem?  I feel like I've seen something about pandigital products.

Comment: A starting point for this problem, if I were to write a search program: If we plot $z=xy$, we find that the curve is highest in the first octant when $x \approx y$, and $x$ and $y$ are large.  Thus, I would look for the largest two numbers I could make with the smallest difference.